# Start Service with C #

Tags: c#, service

I'm trying to start a service with C # but throws me the following error:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(sServiceName);
service.MachineName = localComputerName;
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open service on computer 
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32
>   desiredAccess)    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Stop()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for your permissions. May me you need to run your app (or Visual Studio) from Administrator account.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Access is denied` error indicates to me that the identity under which your process / application is running does not have permission to start & stop services.

Comment: how to set permission then?

Answer (score 1):

Have you red the exception text? you simply have no permission to start a server. Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h846e9b3.aspx ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerpermission.aspx specifically) or simply launch the application as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892088/servicecontroller-permissions-in-windows-7) for some help on permissions when starting your service.