# How can i stop windows service using C#, i want solution according to my code. Not another type

Tags: c#

I create a windows service controller. I use this code for stop a service.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ServiceController myService = new ServiceController();
        myService.ServiceName = "BITS";
        if ((myService.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) || (myService.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)))
        {
            myService.Stop();
            label1.Text = "Service is stop";
        }
}
```

But when i click stop button. It show correct service status. But it is not working for stop this service. When i click there show a error message that

" An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceProcess.dll , Additional information: Cannot open BITS service on computer '.'. "

Anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the service is handling an event which causes the error, i.e. the error has nothing to do with the stopping of the service as such? What happens if you change the service to just do nothing; does the problem remain?

Comment: Maybe your process doesn't have enough permissions to stop the service

Comment: Its a UAC permission problem. You need to run the program as administrator, or turn off uac or add this code to make the system run it as administrator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892088/servicecontroller-permissions-in-windows-7

Comment: Your code snippet says "BITS" but your error says "WSearch". Which is it? Or are you seeing a WSearch errors when stopping BITS, or is this just a copy-paste error to SO?

Comment: You can't stop a service if you don't havew the proper permissions. If you have administrative rights, you should start your application with "Run as Administrator". If not, you should give the appropriate permissions to your account. Some system services though *can't* be stopped even by an administrator