# how to start a windows service from another windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

i have windows service "monitoringservice" (account:localservice) and another service named

"uploadService" (account: local system), i installed the uploadService with setupproject and

when i start this upload service its working fine. but when i start the upload service with

the help of "monitoringservice" iam unable yo start the service  iam getting the below error

**"cannot open uploadService on the computer'.'"**

Can any one suggest me please iam strck up with this problem

i used the following code

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("UploadService");
                    if(sc!=null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running && sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
                            {
                                sc.Start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this other question as it might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545355/stop-start-service-in-code-in-windows-7

Comment: i have gone througth the above link already, but i didnt find exact answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see the following for a description of the local service account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The local service account may not be able to start your other service due to permissions, change the account on your monitoring service to local system

Comment: its a requiremnt from my client...it should be local service....can you please suggest me..how to solve this issue with local service account.. Thank you for your concern..

Comment: It cannot as local service does not have the required permissions to do what your client wants.

Comment: even though i changed it to local system it getting the same error
"cannot open uploadService on the computer'.'"